# Expand only the key-value pairs required by a function

Tags: python

Let's say we have a function that takes some arguments and a dict that is a superset of values required to invoke the function:

```py
d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}

def foo(a, b):
   print(a, b)

# this won't work
foo(**d)

# this works but is tedious the more values there are
foo(**{k: v for k,v in d.items() if k not in ("c")})
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Do you know the names of the `foo`'s parameters, or do you only know which keys are *not* parameters? Something like `foo(*operator.itemgetter('a', 'b')(d))` is an option.

Comment: In general, though, if you are carrying around a `dict` to use as a common argument to a group of functions, you *probably* want to define a class instead. The instance of the class replaces the `dict`, and any methods in the class can access whatever attributes on the instance they need in place of arguments.

Comment: Can you modify the function itself, or limited to the way you call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```py
def foo(a, b):
   print(a, b)
```

You could do this:

```py
def foo(a, b, **kwargs):
   print(a, b)
```

Then the function would just ignore all the unneeded arguments.

However, in my view, there are some problems with this approach.

1. Sometimes you don't own the source code of the function. Of course, you can make lots of wrapper functions. If you do that manually, you'll have to change the signatures of your helper functions every time the library authors modify the function signature.
2. This solution can make some bugs harder to find. Maybe it's better to explicitly state that you're only using some of the elements from the dictionary.

You can still make it easier using the `inspect` module of the standard library.

**a) Make a decorator that makes the function filter its keyword arguments.**

For instance:

```py
import inspect

def filter_kwargs(f):
  arg_names = inspect.getargspec(f).args
  def _f(*args, **kwargs):
    return f(*args, **{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in arg_names})
  return _f

# Use it like this:
filter_kwargs(foo)(a_dict)
```

**b) You can create a function that transforms the *argument* to fit the function**

```py
def fit_for(f, kwargs):
  arg_names = inspect.getargspec(f).args
  return {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in arg_names}

foo(fit_for(foo, a_dict))
```

---

Optionally, you can expand this function to also take into account the `*args` and `**kwargs` in the original function.

---

If this is a recurring pattern in your code, you can just pass the dict as a single argument.

Also, as @chepner pointed out in the comments, consider creating a class.

Comment: I think the `inspect.getfullargspec()` method really helped me out. And yeah, I didn't have access to the source code so I couldn't just catch the arguments normally.

Answer (score 1):

you could use keyword arguments:

```
def foo(**kwarg):
    print(kwarg['a'], kwarg['b'])

foo(**d)
```

output:

```
1 2
```

Comment: Is this really a good idea? In my experience, this can be a source of errors. In JavaScript, for example, you can supply any number of arguments for a function, and it will just ignore them, which can lead to bugs that are hard to find. Maybe it would be better to explicitly state that this dict has to be filtered.

Unless, of course, it's certain that the function is only called in this context, which is hard to ensure.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not want to modify `foo`'s function signature, you can use `foo.__code__.co_varnames` to get the argument names of `foo` **if you are using cpython**

```
foo(**{k: d[k] for k in  foo.__code__.co_varnames})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```py
d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
def foo(a, b, *arg, **kwarg):
    print(a, b)

foo(**d)
```