# Passing extra arguments

Tags: python

Anyone has an idea how to do this

```
def f(a,b):
    print(a)
    print(b)

dct2 = {"a":"Foo", "b":"Bar", "c":"Place"}

f(**dct2)
```

and it still prints only a and b while ignoring c. Any way of doing that? Like ignoring extra arguments.

Comment: @arundeepchohan
not working. throwing error ` f takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given `

Comment: I meant kwargs.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expand only the key-value pairs required by a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727724/expand-only-the-key-value-pairs-required-by-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs['a'])
    print(kwargs['b'])

dct2 = {"a":"Foo", "b":"Bar", "c":"Place"}

f(**dct2)
```

Basically handle the first two but not the rest.